# Angular testing with Karma: "module is not defined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, karma-runner, gulp

I know this question has been asked many times, and I know that in most cases people are missing the `angular-mocks.js` file.

I'm running into the same issue, attempting to test a factory on a module. Unfortunately, I keep running into issues with the tests (why, Angular, oh why must you assume a `window` and `document` object?), which state that module is not defined. I'm at a loss. I've also tried using angular.mocks.module, but then I get a message saying Angular isn't defined. What am I doing wrong?

Of note, I'm using gulp as a task runner. My gulpfile (not yet perfect, tasks aren't linked):

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),

    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
    jasmine = require('gulp-jasmine'), 
    karma = require('gulp-karma'),

    paths = {
        scripts: "scripts/*.js",
        spec: "spec/*.js",
        dist: "dist"
    };

gulp.task('prepare', function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.scripts)
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist))
});

gulp.task('test', function () {
    gulp.src([paths.scripts, paths.spec])
        .pipe(karma({
            configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
            action: 'run'
        }));
});

gulp.task('default', ['prepare', 'test']);
```

My karma.conf.js, generated by karma init:

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Fri Mar 14 2014 14:24:30 GMT-0400 (EDT)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      './lib/angular/angular.min.js',
      './lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      './src/*.js',
      './spec/*.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [

    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {

    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: false,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

And finally, my test suite (nothing's set up yet, if I can pass this hurdle, we'll be good):

```
/* Tests for memento.js. */

describe('memento core test suite', function () {
    var memento;

    beforeEach(module('Memento'));

    beforeEach(function() {
        inject(function(_memento_) {
            memento = _memento_;
        });
    });

    // Check functions.
      // check to see if it has the expected function
    it('should match expected interface', function () { 
        expect(angular.isFunction(memento.canUndo)).toBe(true);
        expect(angular.isFunction(memento.canRedo)).toBe(true);
        expect(angular.isFunction(memento.undo)).toBe(true);
        expect(angular.isFunction(memento.redo)).toBe(true);
        expect(angular.isFunction(memento.push)).toBe(true);
    });

    it('should initialize', function () {
        this.fail(Error('Test not implemented'));
    });

    it('should push() a changed object', function () {
        this.fail(Error('Test not implemented'));
    });

    it('should not push() an unchanged object', function () {
        this.fail(Error('Test not implemented'));
    });

    it('should return original object on undo()', function () {
        this.fail(Error('Test not implemented'));
    });

    it('should return modified object on redo()', function () {
        this.fail(Error('Test not implemented'));
    });

    it('should not undo() if at beginning of stack', function () {
        this.fail(Error('Test not implemented'));
    });

    it('should not redo() if at end of stack', function () {
        this.fail(Error('Test not implemented'));
    });

    // TODO: Implement revert to original, clearing history.
    // 
    // it('should return seed object on revert()', function () {
    //  this.fail(Error('Test not implemented'));
    // });

    // it('should clear the stack on clear()', function () {
    //  this.fail(Error('Test not implemented'));
    // });
});
```

Does anyone see anything awry? I'm not sure if there's something really obvious I'm missing - I could use an extra set of eyes, or many. I originally thought I'd be able to run this as a simple Jasmine test suite without Karma, but due to Angular, that has problems. If I can't get this to work, I might just use npm's Angular package and alter my Angular module so that it supports CommonJS...

Thanks, everyone! Hope I'm not crazy.

Edit: I've included my devdependencies.

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "~3.5.6",
    "gulp-uglify": "~0.2.1",
    "gulp-jshint": "~1.5.0",
    "gulp-jasmine": "~0.2.0",
    "angular": "~1.2.10",
    "karma": "~0.12.0",
    "gulp-karma": "0.0.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.2.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.1.2"
  }
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The message stating that module/angular is not defined means that your angular-mocks.js file is not being loaded, despite the fact you have it listed in your karma.conf.js file.

The problem you're experiencing is gulp-karma ignoring your karma.conf.js files array. This happens when you pass a string or glob into gulp.src in the gulpfile.

To work around this, pass gulp.src a string for a bogus file, "./foobar" for instance, and this will cause the files array in the karma.conf.js file to be used instead.

```
gulp.task('test', function () {
  gulp.src('./foobar')
    .pipe(karma({
      configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
      action: 'run'
    }));
});
```

Hope this helps!

Reference:
https://github.com/lazd/gulp-karma/issues/9

Comment: This was it! What a tripup! Thanks, very good catch on your part.

Comment: I'd have periodic fails with Karma. It would just hang trying to connect to PhantomJS then "exit with code 0" THANK YOU @Himal

Answer (score 1):

This is not the answer to your particular issue,
but I had a similar symptom in a very similar scenario.
However, the root cause was different,
so I'll share it here in case others find this post and they have the same issue I had.

In my case, because I introduced tests later in the game,
there was a **mismatch between the versions** of angular (1.4.7) and angular-mocks (1.6.9).

I found out this was the root cause
by using the debug of Karma in the browser.
Lowering the version of angular-mocks to match angular solved the issue.