# Depending on directory layout Karma tests do or do not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner

Depending on the directory layout tests with Karma do or do not work for me. Why is that, what is the problem in the second case and how can I fix it?

This directory layout works:

```
modules/
  editor/
    filters/
      color.filter.js
      pixel.filter.js
      filters.spec.js
```

This one does not,

```
modules/
  editor/
    filters/
      color.filter.js
      pixel.filter.js
tests/
  editor/
    filters/
      filters.spec.js
```

but causes the following command

```
$ karma start config/karma.js
```

to throw this error message:

```
TypeError: module is not a function in .../tests/editor/filters/filters.spec.js (line 7)
```

Line 7 of `filters.spec.js` reads the following:

```
beforeEach(module('MyApp'));
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22417732/948404) suggests an issue with `angular-mocks.js` not being found, so here is a part of my `config/karma.js`:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

// [...]

// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
  'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
  'bower_components/angular/angular.min.js',
  'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js',
  'modules/**/*.js',
  'tests/**/*.js'
],

// [...]
```

If more information is needed, please tell me in the comments.

Comment: What's the actual name of your module directory? Is it `modules/filters/filters.js`? So does the directory name match the file name?

Comment: I updated with the actual directory layout, there is one more level of nesting inside.